# Apart from Apache and IIS, on which web servers can PHP run?

Tags: php, webserver

I was looking for all possible alternatives for web servers apart from Apache and IIS for PHP to run, but didn't get.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI) or [Lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/TutorialLighttpdAndPHP).